# Random Variables.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution in  $1 \leq k \leq m.$

What is the value of $P(X=k|a\leq X\leq b)?$

In particular find the value of $P(X>n+k|X>n).$

Comment: What is $X$? You never defined it ... Also, over which interval is $T$ uniform? And are you talking about the discrete or continuous uniform distribution?

Comment: I'm Sorry, I just corrected the post.

Comment: No problem! I've posted an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is uniform on $\{1,\dots,m\}$ then 
$$
  P[X > n+k \mid X > n]
= \frac{P[X > n+k]}{P[ X > n]}
= \frac{(m-(n+k))/m}{(m-n)/m}
= \frac{m-(n+k)}{m-n}.
$$
If $1 \leq a < k < b \leq m$ then 
$$
  P[X = k \mid a < X < b ]
= \frac{P[X = k ]}{P[ a < X < b ]}
= \frac{1/m}{(b-a-1)/m}
= \frac{1}{b-a-1}
$$